# Good strategy for using docker with mongo and data

Tags: mongodb, docker

I already have a mongo running on my computer.  I would like to move this to a docker container.
Now, I understand that a container should be immutable,and I agree. 
In this case, how should I actually use my local data or import it to the mongo container?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to import it, you can mount your host mongodb "data" directory to your container's /data directory where your mongodb is running within.  Then your mongodb running inside a container will share the same data as you are currently using with your mongo running on your host.

This link will help:  https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/

If you run mongo in a container and don't mount the data volumes out of the container then when that container stops running the data is gone with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried this, but mongo always complains about permissions.  Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Does the user you are running your docker build/run command have access to your host mongodb data directory?  Sounds like the host is stopping the mongo running in your container from accessing that directory, not sure if it the user executing the container or the mongo instance itself not having access to that folder.